# Extract public key from digital certificate .crt

Tags: ssl-certificate, x509certificate, digital-certificate

I have a digital certificate (with .crt extension) such as:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIGSAgEBMCgGByqGSM49AQECHQD///////////////////////////////7//+Vt
MAYEAQAEAQUEOQShRVszTfCZ3zD8KKFppGfp5HB1qQ9+ZQ62t6Rcfgif7X+6NEKC
yvvW9+MZ98CwvVniykvbVW1hpQIdAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB3OjS7GGEyvCpcXaf
sfcCAQE=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

My question is how can I extract the prime number of the public key from it without knowing anything else? I can not find any online converter ore a structure to figure it out.

Comment: The content you presented is not a digital certificate. This looks like to  details of the parameters associated with a particular curve (ASN.1 ECParameter struct).

Comment: This is a part of a homework about digital signatures. It says that I need to do some operation with the prime number p that can be found in the file with .der extension. I manage to convert the .der extension in .crt and I obtained this text but I can not figure it out witch is the p because of the '/' separator.

Comment: Actually, this is a Base64-encoded byte array of ASN.1 DER-encoded ellyptic curve key parameters, so slashes are not separators. With OpenSSL, you can try this command against your file: `openssl ecparam -in secp256k1.pem -text -param_enc explicit -noout`, where `secp256k1.pem` is your .der file.

Comment: I get `C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin>openssl ecparam -in C:\project\parameters.der -text -param_enc explicit -noout
unable to load elliptic curve parameters
3940:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:crypto\pem\pem_lib.c:691:Expecting: EC PARAMETERS` :(

Comment: This is the file [parameters.der](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/ca337c0111036d6466a818e0cc26465f20170107192352/1adc2d)

Comment: `ECParameters` ASN module is defined in https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3279#section-2.3.5, and your file looks legit `ECParameters` structure: http://imgur.com/a/4qy5V

Comment: So why do i get this error?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I don't have OpenSSL right now.

Comment: Try this command: `openssl ecparam -in ec_param.pem -noout -text` (source: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/ecparam.html)

Comment: I get the same Error :(

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, that file is actually the `EC PARAMETERS` block for an EC key, not a certificate. I found this out by dumping the ASN.1 structures and comparing it to another EC key I generated.

```
$  openssl asn1parse -in test.pem -i -dump
    0:d=0  hl=3 l= 146 cons: SEQUENCE
    3:d=1  hl=2 l=   1 prim:  INTEGER           :01
    6:d=1  hl=2 l=  40 cons:  SEQUENCE
    8:d=2  hl=2 l=   7 prim:   OBJECT            :prime-field
   17:d=2  hl=2 l=  29 prim:   INTEGER           :FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEFFFFE56D
   48:d=1  hl=2 l=   6 cons:  SEQUENCE
   50:d=2  hl=2 l=   1 prim:   OCTET STRING
      0001 - <SPACES/NULS>
   53:d=2  hl=2 l=   1 prim:   OCTET STRING
      0000 - 05                                                .
   56:d=1  hl=2 l=  57 prim:  OCTET STRING
      0000 - 04 a1 45 5b 33 4d f0 99-df 30 fc 28 a1 69 a4 67   ..E[3M...0.(.i.g
      0010 - e9 e4 70 75 a9 0f 7e 65-0e b6 b7 a4 5c 7e 08 9f   ..pu..~e....\~..
      0020 - ed 7f ba 34 42 82 ca fb-d6 f7 e3 19 f7 c0 b0 bd   ...4B...........
      0030 - 59 e2 ca 4b db 55 6d 61-a5                        Y..K.Uma.
  115:d=1  hl=2 l=  29 prim:  INTEGER           :010000000000000000000000000001DCE8D2EC6184CAF0A971769FB1F7
  146:d=1  hl=2 l=   1 prim:  INTEGER           :01
```

Fixing the headers allows you to read the file like this:

```
$  openssl ecparam -in test.pem -text
Field Type: prime-field
Prime:
    00:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:
    ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:fe:ff:ff:e5:6d
A:    0
B:    5 (0x5)
Generator (uncompressed):
    04:a1:45:5b:33:4d:f0:99:df:30:fc:28:a1:69:a4:
    67:e9:e4:70:75:a9:0f:7e:65:0e:b6:b7:a4:5c:7e:
    08:9f:ed:7f:ba:34:42:82:ca:fb:d6:f7:e3:19:f7:
    c0:b0:bd:59:e2:ca:4b:db:55:6d:61:a5
Order:
    01:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:
    dc:e8:d2:ec:61:84:ca:f0:a9:71:76:9f:b1:f7
Cofactor:  1 (0x1)
-----BEGIN EC PARAMETERS-----
MIGSAgEBMCgGByqGSM49AQECHQD///////////////////////////////7//+Vt
MAYEAQAEAQUEOQShRVszTfCZ3zD8KKFppGfp5HB1qQ9+ZQ62t6Rcfgif7X+6NEKC
yvvW9+MZ98CwvVniykvbVW1hpQIdAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB3OjS7GGEyvCpcXaf
sfcCAQE=
-----END EC PARAMETERS-----
```

Which is a more nicely formatted version of the previous output. Notice the correct `BEGIN EC PARAMETERS` instead of `BEGIN CERTIFICATE` header. The prime block is shown in the output above.